# Obsolete [blackberry] tag → ️

Tags: feature-request, tags

I would like to say that the [blackberry](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackberry) is highly obsolete and pretty much dead, nobody longer use such smartphones.

Comment: I wouldn't say you're wrong, but that doesn't mean there won't be any questions about it. Not to mention the score that are already there - we're not gonna just delete them all :-)

Comment: @AviD You're right; but isn't there a "lock tag" option?

Comment: @tungsten What would the point of locking be? And if someone has a good question about an outdated technology, why not let them ask it?

Comment: questions will fastly become "localized" or "personalized" since the population of these devices are deprived. (i don't say these are bad questions)

Comment: One of my work phones is a blackberry - definitely not obsolete. Definitely not going to approve the removal of something like this that is still in use, and even after it is disused, I agree with @MechMK1 - it's still a good tag

Answer (score 7):

No, this tag should not be deleted. Just because blackberries are obsolete doesn't mean that there can't be questions about it. In general, deleting a tag should only be done if there are good reasons to do so.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** And **Is it unambiguous?**

   [blackberry](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackberry) fulfills both of these. It's pretty clear that questions with this tag are about blackberries.
2. **Is the concept described even on-fopic for the site?**

   Yes, questions about the security of [blackberry](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackberry) devices are on-topic, as long as they meet all the other requirements.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   Generally, I would say yes. You can be an expert when it comes to [blackberry](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackberry) security, just like you can be for [android](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android), [iphone](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone) or [linux](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux).
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Depends. It may either refer to the device or the operating system, but they are closely related enough to be functionally interchangable, similar to [android](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android). It's clear that these questions are about the security of Android devices, not about general Android questions.

Having gotten that out of the way, ask yourself if the existence of the tag causes any problems. I would wager that it doesn't. It's not like [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security), which adds absolutely nothing at all, or [policy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policy), which is so ambiguous that adding the tag doesn't really describe anything.

Comment: For a second there I thought there actually was a `security` tag... Don't scare me like that! :-)

Comment: @Anders Luckily not, but I would not be surprized if some newer users tried to ask a question and had no idea what tag to use, then searched to see if maybe "security" was a tag.